# An identity involving $[\sigma(n)]^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

For a positive integer $n$, let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $n$. For example, $\sigma(1)=1$, $\sigma(2)=3$, $\sigma(4)=7$, etc.

I would like to prove the following identity:

> For every positive integer $n$, $$ [\sigma(n)]^2=\sum_{d\mid n}
>  \frac{n}{d} \sigma(d^2)$$
>   where the sum ranges over all divisors $d$ of $n$.

Here is one attempt: We know $\sigma(n)$ is a multiplicative function, that is, $\sigma(ab)=\sigma(a)\sigma(b)$ for $\gcd(a, b)=1$. And I think one can show the right hand side is also multiplicative, so it suffices to check the equality when $n=p^k$ is a prime power. This last task boils down to showing that:
$$
(1+p+\cdots + p^k)^2 = \sum_{0\leq m\leq k} p^{k-m} (1+p+\cdots + p^{2m})
$$
Using the geometric series, the left hand side is $\left(\dfrac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}\right)^2$ and similarly the right hand side is 
$$
\sum_{0\leq m\leq k} p^{k-m} \frac{p^{2m+1}-1}{p-1} 
$$
So we just need to show:
$$
(p^{k+1}-1)^2 = (p-1)\sum_{0\leq m\leq k} p^{k-m}(p^{2m+1}-1) = (p-1) p^{k} \sum_{0\leq m\leq k} (p^{m+1}-p^{-m}) 
$$
and indeed, we can compute that:
$$
(p-1)p^{k} \sum_{0\leq m\leq k} (p^{m+1}-p^{-m})  = (p-1)p^{k}\left(\frac{p^{k+2}-p}{p-1} + \frac{p^{-k+1}-p}{p-1}\right) =
p^{2k+2} -2 p^{k+1} + 1 = (p^{k+1}-1)^2
$$
as desired. Is this proof correct? I am not really satisfied by it, because I don't seem to get any insight out of it. Does anyone have a more conceptual (perhaps combinatorial) proof?

Comment: You need that if $f,g$ are multiplicative, then so is $h(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} f(n/d)g(d)$ to conclude the right side is multiplicative. It is true.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! I knew this operation is called Möbius convolution but didn't realize that it preserves multiplicative property. So that verifies my proof. I'd still love to see an alternative approach (say with double counting).

Comment: Yeah, not seeing it obviously. If $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ then the left side can be written as a sum if $[\tau(n)]^2$ terms and the right side can be written as the sum of $$\sum_{d\mid n} \tau(d^2)$$ terms. Again, restricting to $n$ a prime power first, we see that $[\tau(n)]^2=\sum_{d\mid n} \tau(d^2)$. So there might be a way to do a re-arrangement of the two double sums.

Comment: This also might suggest more generally that if $\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} d^k$ (so $\sigma=\sigma_1, \tau=\sigma_0$) then: $\sigma_k(n)^2 = \sum_{d\mid n} \left(\frac nd\right)^k\sigma_k(d^2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a direct-ish proof. at least, without using that the various functions are multiplicative.

First, let's prove a pair of counting lemmas.

**Lemma 1**: If $m\mid n^2$, then the number of ways to write $m=d_1d_2$ with $d_1\mid n$ and $d_2\mid n$ is equal to the number of divisors of $\gcd\left(m,\frac{n^2}{m}\right)$.

**Proof**: We need both that $d_1\mid m$ and $d_1\mid n$. So we need $d_1\mid \gcd(m,n)$. We also need $d_2=\frac{m}{d_1}\mid n$, so $\frac{m}{d_1}\mid\gcd(m,n)$ or $\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}\mid d_1 $. Therefore, we can choose any $d_1$ with:

$$\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}\mid d_1\mid \gcd(m,n)$$

If we let $d=\frac{d_1\gcd(m,n)}{m}$, we can pick any $d$ with $$d\mid\frac{\gcd(n,m)^2}{m}=\gcd\left(\frac{n^2}{m},m\right).$$

**Lemma 2:** If $m\mid n^2$, then the number of ways to write $m=\frac{n}{d_1}d_2$ with $d_1\mid n$ and $d_2\mid d_1^2$ is also equal to the number of divisors of $\gcd\left(\frac{n^2}{m},m\right)$.

**Proof**: Note that $\gcd\left(\frac{n^2}{m},m\right)\mid n$ (this follows from $\gcd(m^2,n^2)=\gcd(m,n)^2\mid mn$.)

So, if $d\mid \gcd\left(\frac{n^2}{m},m\right)$ then $d\mid n$ so let $d_1=\frac nd$ and let $d_2=\frac{md_1}{n}=\frac{m}{d}$, which is an integer.

Now, $\frac{d_1^2}{d_2} = \frac{n^2}{d^2}\frac{d}{m} = \frac{n^2}{md}$. But $d$ is a divisor of $\frac{n^2}m$ by definition, so this is an integer, and $d_2\mid d_1^2$.

On the other hand, if we have a pair $d_1,d_2$ with $\frac{n}{d_1}d_2=m$ and $d_1\mid n$ and $d_2\mid d_1^2$, then let $d=\frac{n}{d_1}$. We clearly have $d\mid n$.

Writing $\frac{n^2}{m}=\frac{n^2}{dd_2} = d\frac{d_1^2}{d_2}$ which is divisible by $d$.

**Theorem:** Let $\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} d^k$. Then:

$$\left[\sigma_k(n)\right]^2 = \sum_{d\mid n} \left(\frac{n}{d}\right)^k\sigma_k(d^2)$$

**Proof**: Both sides can be written as a sum of $k$th powers of divisors $m$ of $n^2$. The number of times $m^k$ occurs on the left side is counted in Lemma 1. The number of times $m$ occurs in the sum on the right side is counted by Lemma 2. These two values are the same.

---

It still feels almost accidental.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot. It is good that I also learned this nice little fact $m\mid n^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $\gcd(\frac{n^2}{m}, m) \mid n$ from this post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but I believe there is a relatively simple way of seeing that 
$$(1 + p + ... + p^k)^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^k p^{k-m}(1 + p + ... + p^{2m})$$
Namely, let us consider the coefficient of $p^j$ on both sides of the above equation.

On the left hand side, this is clearly equal to the number of ways of writing $p^j = p^rp^s = p^{r+s}$ with $0 \leq r,s \leq k$, so it's the number of ways of writing $j = r+s$ with $0 \leq r,s \leq k$. Now if $j \leq k$, then this is possible for $r = 0,...,j$ and if $j \geq k$, it is possible for $r = j-k,...,k$.

On the right hand side, this coefficient is the number of $m$ such that the above sum contains $p^j$, which is clearly the number of $m$ such that $k-m \leq j \leq k+m$, with $0 \leq m \leq k$. Again, if $j \leq k$, then this is true
for $m = k-j,...,k$ and if $j \geq k$, it is true for $m = j-k,...,k$.

Thus the coefficient of $p^j$ is the same on both sides so they must be equal.

Comment: Even though it only gives the proof for prime power case, this is a cool approach. Thanks!

Comment: This argument actual extends more generally. See my answer. It's a bit messy, but you still just are re-arranging terms in a double sum.